# How to cancel a realm transaction in process

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to `cancel` a `transaction` in `Realm`, inside of my `RealmRecyclerView` when an item is deleted, a `Snackbar` is presented, making it possible to `undo` the request. When I make multiple delete requests, an exception is thrown. I am reading about `asynchronous transactions` but I do not know how to `track` the transaction.

```
public void deleteItem(View view, int position) {
    if (getData() != null && getData().getPosition(position).isValid()) {
        MyObjectRealm item = getData().getPosition(position);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        item.deleteFromRealm();
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        showSnackbar(view, position);
    }
}

private void showSnackbar(View view, int position) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, context.getString(R.string.removed), Snackbar.LENGHT_SHORT);
    snackbar.setAction(context.getString(R.string.undo), new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (realm.isInTransaction()) {
                realm.cancelTransaction();
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
            }
        }
    });
    snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int event) {
            if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Exception:

```
03-27 17:28:14.345 17667-17667/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example, PID: 17667
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Realm is already in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 131
                                                                     at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeBeginTransaction(Native Method)
                                                                     at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.beginTransaction(SharedRealm.java:237)
                                                                     at io.realm.BaseRealm.beginTransaction(BaseRealm.java:309)
                                                                     at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:126)
                                                                     at com.example.adapter.MyAdapter.deleteItem(MyAdapter.java:90)
                                                                     at com.example.util.SwipeHelper.onSwiped(SwipeHelper.java:32)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$4.run(ItemTouchHelper.java:686)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: how about `if(!realm.isInTransaction()) { realm.beginTransaction(); }`?

Comment: It works, but it only prevents the exception, in the case of deleting a new item shortly after it is not removed.

Comment: What if the user clicks on `deleteItem` multiple time (before s/he choose to dismiss/undo the Snackbar)  in this case you end up with trying to open a new transaction, while one is pending to be committed/canceled. I think this is what could explains the error you're seeing